# R: Conditional diff function

Tags: r, group-by, diff

I would like to calculate the consecutive differences between the rows of a variable of a dataframe in R, exactly like the `diff()` function, however, only between the rows with the same id number.

Dummy data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

t1 <- c(4,3,4,4,5,8,9,11,3,8,9,7,9,10,3)

df <- data.frame(id, t1)
```

Using `diff(df$t1)` I get:

> -1  1  0  1  3  1  2 -8  5  1 -2  2  1 -7

I would like:

> -1  1  0  1  3  1  NA -8  5  1 -2  2  1 -7

I tried also:

```
df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  diff(df$t1)
```

But I get the error:

> Error in diff.default(., df$t1) :    'lag' and 'differences' must be
> integers >= 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to move `diff()` to inside a `mutate()` statement if you are using `dplyr`. But `diff()` returns a vector that's shorter by 1 than your input vector which makes it difficult to keep the same number of rows. An alternative is to use the `dplyr` `lead()` function to grab the "next" value in the group

```
df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(diff=lead(t1)-t1)
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner base R could be

```
ave(df$t1, df$id, FUN = function(x) c(x[-1], NA) - x)
#[1] -1  1  0  1  3  1  2 NA  5  1 -2  2  1 -7 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Diff = shift(t1, type = 'lead') - t1, id]
```